# Unable to import/export photos using Digikam

Tags: kde, digikam, kde-apps

I am trying to use the option import or export photos in Digikam to Google photos. Every time I click the option, a window opens up and crashes the whole program.

The error in terminal says:
`Error initializing NSS without a persistent database`